# How can I delete duplicate words in text file

Tags: awk, grep, duplicates

I have text file:

```
abandonovať
abandonovať, neabandonovať
abandonovať, abandonujem
abandonovať, abandonuješ
abandonovať, abandonuje
abandonovať, abandonuje
abandonovať, abandonuje
abandonovať, neabandonujem
abandonovať, neabandonuješ
```

And I want remove every duplicate word. It will look like this:

```
abandonovať
neabandonovať
abandonujem
abandonuješ
abandonuje
neabandonujem
neabandonuješ
```

Have somebody any idea how to make it in GREP, AWK... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may try to use:

```
grep -o '\w*' a.txt | sort | uniq
```

where a.txt is your file.

Comment: It works but in my text file I have words like "nebudem abandonovať" which is negative to "abandonovať" but this command delete "abandonovať" and only "nebudem" stays. How to solve this?

Comment: you may use `'\(\w\+\s\)\?\w*'` as a pattern

Comment: Thank you. And if I dont want to sort words by alphabet?

Comment: if you don't `sort`, you cannot use `uniq` to remove duplicates. or you may try steve's solution below, it might work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F "[, ]" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++ && $i != "") print $i }' file
```

Results:

```
abandonovať
neabandonovať
abandonujem
abandonuješ
abandonuje
neabandonujem
neabandonuješ
```

Comment: on a second thought, it looks like this might fail if there are extra spaces somewhere in the line?

Comment: Those extra spaces would have to be preceded by a comma. But if that's the case, then the var is probably some sort of word.

Comment: It works but in my text file I have words like "nebudem abandonovať" which is negative to "abandonovať" but this command delete "abandonovať" and only "nebudem" stays. How to solve this?

Comment: @user1844845: I would ask that you check again. This command will only separate words by the ", " delimiter (i.e. a comma then a space). Therefore "nebudem abandonovať" would be treated as a single word. If you'd like further assistance, please post some more sample data (and let me know by adding a comment here). Cheers.

Comment: `a[$i]++; if (a[$i]==1) print $i` could be written as `if (!a[$i]++) print $i`. !seen["foo"]++ is the idiomatic awk way to check if "foo" has been seen before or not.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks mate. Must have missed that.

Comment: @user1844845: I've updated the solution, slightly. It may work 'better' for you. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, In GREP it works but it sort words by alphabet. In AWK it also works, but I have one more little problem. My text file is:

```
abandonovať
abandonovať, neabandonovať
abandonovať, abandonujem
.
.
.
```

If I enter your code in awk my result is:

```
abandonovať
abandonovať,
neabandonovať
abandonujem
.
.
.
```

One word is there twice. Once with "," and once without ",".